# What is wrong MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateRank BEFORE UPDATE ON question
SELECT SUM(favouriteCount) as fav FROM question WHERE created_user = NEW.created_user
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET rank = (SELECT id FROM Rank WHERE fav > range) WHERE id=NEW.created_user
    END
```

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `'SELECT SUM(favouriteCount) as fav FROM question WHERE created_user = NEW.created'` at line 2

How to fix it ?

[Question table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSm4v.png)

[Rank table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregation functions like that for a trigger.  But you can move the logic into the `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateRank BEFORE UPDATE ON question
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users u CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT SUM(favouriteCount) as fav
                FROM question
                WHERE created_user = NEW.created_user
               ) f
            SET rank = (SELECT r.id FROM Rank r WHERE f.fav > r.range)
            WHERE u.id = NEW.created_user;
    END;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: Perhaps you need `delimiter` statements to use semicolons properly in the definition.